# Force close window in Async task execute

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Force close window, When Async task execute after connection is loss.
I'm tired using ConnectivityManager to check internet connection, because when device connect to wifi but no internet connection, ConnectivityManager showing is connected. can any body help me?

```
public boolean isConnected(){
        boolean status=false;
        ConnectivityManager cManager=(ConnectivityManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo[] allNetworkInfo = cManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i<allNetworkInfo.length; i++){
            if (allNetworkInfo[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
                status = true;
            }
        }
        return  status;
    }
```

Comment: Question is unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost done but need to check it also that network is connecting or connected.

```
public boolean isConnected(){
        boolean status=false;
        ConnectivityManager cManager=(ConnectivityManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo[] allNetworkInfo = cManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i<allNetworkInfo.length; i++){
            if (allNetworkInfo[i].isConnectedOrConnecting()){
                status = true;
            }
        }
        return  status;
    }
```

I Hope it helps you...

Comment: work when wifi switch off, but not when wifi is on

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to see if it works:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works for me.

```
public static boolean isConnectedWithInternet(Context context) {
            // return true;
            boolean _isNetAvailable = false;
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            if (wifiNetwork != null) {
                _isNetAvailable = wifiNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }

            NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            if (mobileNetwork != null) {
                _isNetAvailable = mobileNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null) {
                _isNetAvailable = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }
            // CGlobalVariables._isInternetOn = _isNetAvailable;

            return _isNetAvailable;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally get an `UnknownHostException` when Internet is not reachable.

You should always check connected state before starting the request. But to handle connection loss during the process you can always catch `UnknownHostException`.